# Easily switch between single and double precision

Tags: performance, vba, excel, precision

To switch between single and double precision in C we use something like:

```
#ifdef USE_DOUBLE
typedef double data_t;
#else
typedef float data_t;
#endif
```

Is there an easy way to perform the same thing so that I can easily switch between the two in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBS, user defined types are abstracted as Classes. For e.g.

```
Public Const PRECISION = 1

Class data_t
    Private dValue

    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        dValue = 0
    End Sub

    Public Property Get Value 'inside out
        Value = dValue
    End Property

    Public Property Let Value(val) 'outside in
        If PRECISION = 1 Then
            dValue = CSng(val)
        Else
            dValue = CDbl(val)
        End If
    End Property    
End Class

Set obj = New data_t
obj.Value = 0.00000011920928955078125
Msgbox obj.Value
```

If PRECISION = 1, the output would be 1.192093E-07

Else the output would be 1.19209289550781E-07

You can easily modify the above code in VBA by adding a class module.

Comment: This is a nice solution but is it efficient performance-wise?

Comment: Its as efficient (or inefficient) as creating/using any object.

Answer (score 0):

This works nearly the same in VBA:

```
#Const USE_DOUBLE = False

#If USE_DOUBLE Then
    Public data As Integer
#Else
    Public data As Double
#End If
```

The `#` stands for conditional compilation.

Comment: It's not exactly the same, using this code I would have to put this condition on every variable, whereas in C I put the condition once on the type declaration and declare the variables as type "data"

Comment: Oh, yeah I misunderstood your code. But still, this is the only way that works in VBA...